# Change name of webroot directory to some other name in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I want to change name of root directory(webroot) in cakephp so is there any way to do so?

Want to hide from user that site build in cakephp, so is there any other technique to do so?

I am using cakephp 2.3.9,

I have did enough goggling for this, after that I have asked question here so please dont down vote it. if its not possible just comment it

```
-app
--Config
--Console
--Controller
--Lib
--Locale
--Model
--Plugin
--View
--webroot (now want to rename this directory name)
---js
---css
---img
-lib
-plugins
```

[image]

I dont want to move that folder to any other place just want to rename it

Comment: Please write more info, directory structure. We can't understand what do you want from your small description.

Comment: `Want to hide from user that site build in cakephp` - renaming the webroot dir is going to do nothing except, depending on how the app is installed, break the app. I recommend clarifying exactly what you want to achieve, rather than about a specific (probably flawed) solution.

Comment: @AD7six if you will go for view page source on cakephp site then there are all css and js load from webrrot folder, so I want to rename that webroot folder

Comment: Create one sub domain for css and js, say http://static.yoursite.com and pull your css and js from this url. Overwrite Form helper for path...

Answer (score 1):

in /app/webroot/index.php or new case /app/new-name/index.php add these lines:

```
define('WWW_ROOT', '/full/path/to/new-name/');
define('WEBROOT_DIR', 'new-name');
```

Comment: Although this doesn't answer the question, I have the feeling you ask because you're accessing your application like `http://example.com/webroot`. There's no other way `webroot` is visible as a name  to the user so you'd want to obfiscate it. But it's a bad idea to do that because other folders are or could be accessed from the url or some malicious script (i.e. `http://example.com/Config` or `http://example.com/Controller`). Instead make `webroot` the root for your application or web site alias.

Comment: I dont want to move that folder to any other place just want to rename it

Comment: You want, or you failed at some basic security for your app. And in fact you don't move the folder but you point the root for this vhost to webroot and not the directory above.

Comment: Create one sub domain for css and js, say http://static.yoursite.com and pull your css and js from this url.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read this:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html

Possibly answers your question?